# Glimpse logging from class library

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, glimpse

I have a ASP.NET MVC project with Glimpse. I use Debug.WriteLine for loging and I see te "logs" in Glimpse.

I have a class library referenced by the ASP.NET MVC project. When I use Debug.WriteLine in the class library, it failes on "Value cannot be null" and the stacktrace says that HttpContext is null.

My question is, how to get around it or how to setup Glimpse to be able to log messages from a class library referencet by ASP.NET MVC project.

Comment: Is it safe to assume that the library you are using is logging on a separate (non-asp.net) thread?